# Oracle 10g Tracefile not being created

Tags: oracle, file, trace

We're having issues with a table that is locking up in our system, so we decided to put a tracefile so we can gather more info about it. Here's what we've done:

```
 alter session set tracefile_identifier='10046USERLOGINNR';
 alter session set timed_statistics = true; 
 alter session set statistics_level=all; 
 alter session set max_dump_file_size = unlimited;
 alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever,level 12';
 //UPDATE SQL STATEMENTS 
 alter session set events '10046 trace name context off';
```

However, and for some reason that we can't identify yet, the trace file `10046USERLOGINNR` does not get created.

Anything we're missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like what you're doing should be working.  The things I can think of to check are:

Are you looking in the right place?  The trace file should go into the directory indicated by the `USER_DUMP_DEST` database parameter.

Does the Oracle OS account have write privilege on the directory?  If not creation of the trace file will silently fail.

If you're on Windows, you could use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to check all the open file handles for oracle.exe after activating tracing.  If the file is going to an unexpected location for some reason, you'll find it this way.  Presumably there's some way you could check the same thing on other operating systems as well.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I will check the permissions for our user on that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Daft theory, but double check the udump_dest_dir setting. Might be getting created somewhere unexpected. (on that, also check bdump for shared server connections).